# Can I delete Core Data's dynamically generated methods in Xcode 4?

Tags: core-data

Core Data generated these four methods. Can I delete them because they're generated dynamically, right?

```
@implementation User
// . . .
@dynamic authorizations;

- (void)addAuthorizationsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"authorizations"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeAuthorizationsObject:(NSManagedObject *)value {
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"authorizations"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addAuthorizations:(NSSet *)value {    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"authorizations"] unionSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

- (void)removeAuthorizations:(NSSet *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"authorizations"] minusSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"authorizations" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}
```

#### Related links:

- [Core Data methods not in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564597/core-data-methods-not-in-header-file)
- [Xcode4: Different code generated for custom core data managed objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253753/xcode4-different-code-generated-for-custom-core-data-managed-objects)
- http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as you leave the `@dynamic` command the accessors will be generated at runtime.