# How should I add items to a list in Core Data now that xcode 4 changed the generated code?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, xcode4

I have a core data model with a parent item and child items under it.  In Xcode 3, when I generated the NSManagedObjects for this, I had methods called addChildsObject object method on Parent, but this has gone away in Xcode 4 (see [Xcode4: Different code generated for custom core data managed objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253753/xcode4-different-code-generated-for-custom-core-data-managed-objects)).  My question is this: how should I be adding the children to the parent now?  I really don't want to mess with the generated code, revert to using Xcode3, or add a category to Parent to bring back the missing methods.  Is there an approved way, or did Apple just muck up the whole process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discovering and reviewing the [documentation on Dynamically-Generated Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOs.html), it appears that Apple still recommends using the now non-existent methods, so it would appear that they have just screwed up by removing them.  There is, however, another recommended way of doing this:

```
NSMutableSet *children = [parent mutableSetValueForKey:@"child"];
[children addObject: child1];
[children removeObject: child2];
```

This is not fabulous, because it relies on an unchecked string name, but it's the only remaining recommended way to do this without custom implementations.  Thanks a lot Apple!